# Packaging Library with another library aar in Kotlin(build.gradle.kts)

Tags: android, maven, repository, gradle-kotlin-dsl, aar

I am creating a library project (lets say B) and I have a dependency for another library (let's say A) which I have in the form of an aar (a.aar) file.

When I build b.aar should be packaged in a way that the a.aar will be bundled inside b.aar

Main Project is not controlled by us, so I do not have control to get a.aar while building the main project and they are looking for a way to bundle a.aar while we build b.aar.

Below is the b build.gradle.kts file.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
    id("gradle-****-android-module")
   id("maven-publish")
}

group = "com.****.******" 
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

android {
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 33

        consumerProguardFiles("proguard-rules.pro")

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha06")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")

    implementation("com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.7")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-image-labeling:16.0.8")
    implementation("com.example.servicelibrary:servicelibrary:1.0")
}
```

And in my repositories section, I'm trying to load the a.aar file from local maven.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    val agpVersion: String by project
    val repositoryUrl = "file:${rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath}/repository"

    repositories {
        maven(url = repositoryUrl)
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("file://home/*******/.m2/repository/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        val pmcModuleVersion: String by project
        val kotlinVersion: String by project

        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agpVersion")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "$kotlinVersion"))
        classpath("com.****.gradle.plugins:gradle-****-android-module:$pmcModuleVersion")
    }
}


allprojects {
    val repositoryUrl = "file:${rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath}/repository"
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven(url = repositoryUrl)
            maven {
                url = uri("file://home/*******/.m2/repository/")
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = repositoryUrl)
        maven {
            url = uri("file://home/*******/.m2/repository/")
        }
    }
}
tasks {
    val clean by registering(Delete::class) {
        delete(builder)
    }
}
```

Any inputs will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

In order to bundle LibraryA while building LibraryB, you will need to include LibraryA as a dependency in the build.gradle file of LibraryB.

Follow the steps mentioned below-

1. Paste ‘**LibraryA**’ inside the android’s project directory outside the **app** folder.
2. In the app level gradle i.e in 'build.gradle(:app)' file of LibraryB, add the following line to the dependencies section:

   **implementation project(':libraryA')**
3. Make sure that the libraryA module is included in the 'settings.gradle' file of the project

   **include ':libraryA' //below include ':app'**
4. If their are modules in LibraryA (Eg. Firebase or OneSignalConfig etc) and is mandatory to use then add the module's implementation also in the **step 2** -

   **implementation project(':LibraryA:<module_name>') //add below implementation project(':libraryA')**

   **example - implementation project(':LibraryA:Firebase')**

**Now try to build and run the app**

**IN CASE OF ANY DEPENDENCY ERROR WHILE BUILDING/RUNNING THE APP, TRY BELOW STEP**

1. If using latest android structure then Add below code in 'settings.gradle' inside **dependencyResolutionManagement{}** and inside **pluginManagement{}**

   **repositories {
   ..
   maven{url 'https://jitpack.io'} //add this below mavenCentral()
   }**
2. If you are using old android structure, then in project level gradle i.e in 'build.gradle(project_name)' add inside **allprojects{}**-

   **repositories {
   ..
   maven{url 'https://jitpack.io'} //add below jcenter() and google()
   }**